# polars help in creating a column on the fly after groupby

Tags: group-by, python-polars

Here are two polars dfs. DF and serdf.
[DF Polars dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOEHy.png) 
[Serdf Polars dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKmXu.png)
For sake of replication of data i have converted it to pandas as below:

```
DF=pd.DataFrame({'client': {0: 'x',1: 'y',
2: 'z', 3: 'k', 4: 'z', 5: 'k', 6: 'y', 7: 'y', 8: 'k', 9: 'z',
10: 'x', 11: 'k', 12: 'x', 13: 'y', 14: 'k', 15: 'z', 16: 'x',
17: 'z', 18: 'k', 19: 'y', 20: 'x', 21: 'z', 22: 'k'},
'a': {0: 34, 1: 31, 2: 3, 3: 10, 4: 11, 5: 4, 6: 11,
7: 12, 8: 87, 9: 90, 10: 56, 11: 88, 12: 12, 13: 45,
14: 67, 15: 81, 16: 12, 17: 18, 18: 7, 19: 56, 20: 11,
21: 34, 22: 15},
'b': {0: 13, 1: 23, 2: 12, 3: 1, 4: 3, 5: 13, 6: 10,7: 67,
8: 90, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 34, 12: 9, 13: 87, 14: 34, 15: 11,
16: 90, 17: 11, 18: 65, 19: 19, 20: 47, 21: 92, 22: 11}})

serdf = pd.DataFrame({'df1': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 7, 4: 9,
5: 11, 6: 13, 7: 15, 8: 17, 9: 19, 10: 21,11: 23, 12: 25,
13: 27, 14: 29, 15: 31, 16: 33, 17: 35, 18: 37, 19: 39,
20: 41, 21: 43, 22: 45, 23: 47},
'df2': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 6, 3: 8, 4: 10, 5: 12, 6: 14, 7: 16,
8: 18, 9: 20, 10: 22, 11: 24, 12: 26, 13: 28, 14: 30,
15: 32, 16: 34, 17: 36, 18: 38, 19: 40, 20: 42, 21: 44,
22: 46, 23: 48},
'df3': {0: -1, 1: -3, 2: -1, 3: 7, 4: -2, 5: -1, 6: -3,
7: 7, 8: -1, 9: 90, 10: -1, 11: -1, 12: 8, 13: -1, 14: -1,
15: 6, 16: -1, 17: 4, 18: -3, 19: 2, 20: -1, 21: -1,
22: -4, 23: -8},
'df4': {0: 3,  1: 7,  2: -1,  3: -8,  4: -2,  5: -1,  6: -9,
7: -1,  8: 12,  9: -1,  10: -1,  11: -1,  12: 11,  13: -1,
14: -1,  15: 1,  16: -1, 17: 2, 18: -3, 19: -1, 20: 41,
21: -1, 22: -4, 23: -8}}
)
```

What I am trying to do is to create new columns on the fly on DF groupedby client; The first groupby object will have a new column that is the first row number of the the first column of serdf for groupby object client x, the second groupby object will have the column that contains first row number of the second column of serdf for groupy object client y and so on. After one iteration I am doing this for all rows of serdf.

As a pseudo code:

```
for i in range(len(serdf)):
    for j in DF.groupedby(client)
        J.CreateNewColumn = serdf[i,j]
```

For simplicity i have taken only the snapshot of serdf. it contains half a million rows. So for example after first iteration,
DF.groupedby with client x  will be,

```
    ----------------------       
|client| a |  b | df1|
    -------------------- |
|  x  | 34| 13 |  1  |
|  x  | 12| 9  |  1  |
|  x  | 11| 47 |  1  |
|  x  | 56| 11 |  1  |
|  x  | 12| 90 |  1  |
----------------------

    DF.groupedby with client y will be,
    ----------------------       
|client| a |  b | df1|
    -------------------- |
|  y  | 31| 23 |  2  |
|  y  | 12| 10 |  2  |
|  y  | 12| 67 |  2  |
|  y  | 45| 87 |  2  |
|  y  | 56| 19 |  2  |
----------------------
```

and so on.

so in total there will be 552 dataframes created on the fly out of this operation; Is it possible to do this without loops at all please?

I do not know how to proceed. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on what I understand of your problem, you could do the following:

```
out = (
    df_pl.join( serdf_pl.with_row_count(), how='cross')
    .partition_by('row_nr','client')
)

[shape: (5, 8)
 ┌────────┬─────┬─────┬────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
 │ client ┆ a   ┆ b   ┆ row_nr ┆ df1 ┆ df2 ┆ df3 ┆ df4 │
 │ ---    ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---    ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
 │ str    ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ u32    ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
 ╞════════╪═════╪═════╪════════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
 │ x      ┆ 34  ┆ 13  ┆ 0      ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ -1  ┆ 3   │
 │ x      ┆ 56  ┆ 10  ┆ 0      ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ -1  ┆ 3   │
 │ x      ┆ 12  ┆ 9   ┆ 0      ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ -1  ┆ 3   │
 │ x      ┆ 12  ┆ 90  ┆ 0      ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ -1  ┆ 3   │
 │ x      ┆ 11  ┆ 47  ┆ 0      ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ -1  ┆ 3   │
 └────────┴─────┴─────┴────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘,
 shape: (5, 8)
 ┌────────┬─────┬─────┬────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
 │ client ┆ a   ┆ b   ┆ row_nr ┆ df1 ┆ df2 ┆ df3 ┆ df4 │
 │ ---    ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---    ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
 │ str    ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ u32    ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
 ╞════════╪═════╪═════╪════════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
 │ y      ┆ 31  ┆ 23  ┆ 0      ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ -1  ┆ 3   │
 │ y      ┆ 11  ┆ 10  ┆ 0      ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ -1  ┆ 3   │
 │ y      ┆ 12  ┆ 67  ┆ 0      ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ -1  ┆ 3   │
 │ y      ┆ 45  ┆ 87  ┆ 0      ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ -1  ┆ 3   │
 │ y      ┆ 56  ┆ 19  ┆ 0      ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ -1  ┆ 3   │
 └────────┴─────┴─────┴────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

The result is a list of 96 dataframes.

Here is what it does:

- it joins the dataframe df and serdf by joining each row of each dataframe. It does that by creating a dummy column 'ones'
- then it partitions the dataframe into multiple dataframe, based on each row of serdf and each client in df

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Hey @Luca - there is also a [`how="cross"`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/howcani/combining_data/joining.html#cross-join)

Comment: @Luca, this is great and simple. It definitely solves the problem. Only thing is I do not need all the columns; depending on the client the column changes. So for x it is df1, for y it is df2 and so on. But I guess I can always drop the unwanted columns after the join. This is so clean code. Thank you very much. For an old school guy like me used to loops, vectorisation is magic! Of course, it is not as fast as say C may be but for the beauty and clarity this is superb. Polars is really fast. Thank you Luca.

Comment: @jqurious: nice add. i didn't realize Polars also had cross join. this makes for an ever shorter code

Comment: @LeeBoy that's good to hear. I updated the answer using the cross join. you can check it out, it might be faster

Comment: @Luca , As i mentioned I have more than half a million rows on serdf and when I run that code I get the error: ComputeError: Cross joins would produce more rows than fits into 2^32.
Consider comping with polars-big-idx feature, or set 'streaming'.

Comment: Hi @LeeBoy, 

You can set streaming the following way: (
    df_pl.lazy().join( serdf_pl.lazy().with_row_count(), how='cross')
    .collect(streaming=True).partition_by('row_nr','client')
)

Instead of adding `.lazy()`, you can use `scan` instead of `read` when reading the file. (that's better)

However if you want the result to be a list of dataframes, then it needs to fit into memory. 

How will you use that after? If you are saving that to disk, then you can use sink_parquet() instead of collect(). This way, you are not loading it to memory, and streaming it directly to disk.

Comment: Thank you @Luca. I will try that. I have one question though: Ido not want all columns to be joined. The columns that need to be joined are client specific. Will that make a difference in memory management and processing time? Is it better to drop the unwanted columns immediately after join or is it better to join only the relevant columns at the time of join. Any argumewnt to pass for this please? Many thanks.

Comment: Hi @LeeBoy, if you do it in lazy mode then Polars should optimize that for you. It should not matter if you drop the columns before and after the join. However, you can still check it by yourself to ensure that.

I'd say that what can really help is looking at what you will do with your list of dataframes. If you'll write it to a file, then better to never collect it, and directly sink it to a file.